# Trying to deploy a NodeJS app via Google App Engine - received an error code 203

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a small app using Google App Engine for my class. Basically I'm porting an I created previously and trying to port it to be used in google app engine. At the moment, I can run it in the cloud shell no problem, but once it is deployed I receive an Error Code 500 at the site provided.

When going through the logs I received what is posted below. I honestly don't entirely know what I'm looking at and any help would be appreciated. All I found was an error code 203 and don't exactly know where to go from there. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appId": "p~assignment8-rev",
    "versionId": "20210413t005916",
    "requestId": "6074f1f100ff097625d7b7fc350001707e61737369676e6d656e74382d7265760001323032313034313374303035393136000100",
    "ip": "24.247.86.162",
    "startTime": "2021-04-13T01:20:49.620250Z",
    "endTime": "2021-04-13T01:20:52.037612Z",
    "latency": "2.417362s",
    "megaCycles": "306",
    "method": "GET",
    "resource": "/",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 500,
    "referrer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36",
    "urlMapEntry": "auto",
    "host": "assignment8-rev.ue.r.appspot.com",
    "wasLoadingRequest": true,
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "finished": true,
    "instanceId": "00c61b117cf471e48880eb4a4b89023626614b83c732a55de5e37d7b755c2001a6faba5bcebab0de734f6d9764be32d6b03ce28d2e820012612b75876d3b386945",
    "line": [
      {
        "time": "2021-04-13T01:20:52.037496Z",
        "severity": "INFO",
        "logMessage": "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-04-13T01:20:52.037497Z",
        "severity": "WARNING",
        "logMessage": "The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)"
      }
    ],
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.71",
    "traceId": "83f7df46cfc2499fb3d121d45acd374c",
    "first": true,
    "traceSampled": true
  },
  "insertId": "6074f1f4000094b7f99e30aa",
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 500
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "assignment8-rev",
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "us-east1-3",
      "version_id": "20210413t005916"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-04-13T01:20:49.620250Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117cf471e48880eb4a4b89023626614b83c732a55de5e37d7b755c2001a6faba5bcebab0de734f6d9764be32d6b03ce28d2e820012612b75876d3b386945"
  },
  "logName": "projects/assignment8-rev/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "6074f1f100ff097625d7b7fc350001707e61737369676e6d656e74382d7265760001323032313034313374303035393136000100",
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/assignment8-rev/traces/83f7df46cfc2499fb3d121d45acd374c",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-04-13T01:20:52.041874812Z",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

Comment: 203 code is normally caused by errors in the application's code resulting the RPC channel to the instance becoming unresponsive or closing. Have you checked that your code is working as expected? On the other hand, have you checked if your App Engine is not performing a task that takes a lot of time to be completed?

Comment: When I run the application on the local host it runs as expected. But once I try and port it over to app engine it crashes when I try to navigate to the web address. I don't know if I configured the yaml incorrectly or not. I'm just trying to get it to run.

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using as well as your yaml file?